# Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import in news retrieving

Tags: python

I'm trying to retrieve some news articles by their URLs through this script, But after I run the code I got an error like this.

How am I supposed to modify my code to avoid that error?

```
import hashlib
import json
import logging
import os
from newsplease import NewsPlease
from ..crawler import commoncrawl_crawler as commoncrawl_crawler

def __setup__():
...
def __get_pretty_filepath(path, article):
...
def on_valid_article_extracted(article):

if __name__ == '__main__':
    __setup__()
    commoncrawl_crawler.crawl_from_commoncrawl(on_valid_article_extracted,
                                               valid_hosts=my_filter_valid_hosts,
                                               start_date=my_filter_start_date,
                                               end_date=my_filter_end_date,
                                               strict_date=my_filter_strict_date,
                                               reuse_previously_downloaded_files=my_reuse_previously_downloaded_files,
                                               local_download_dir_warc=my_local_download_dir_warc,
                                               continue_after_error=my_continue_after_error,
                                               show_download_progress=my_show_download_progress,
                                               number_of_extraction_processes=my_number_of_extraction_processes,
                                               log_level=my_log_level,
                                               delete_warc_after_extraction=True,
                                               continue_process=True)


article = NewsPlease.from_url('https://www.nytimes.com/2017/02/23/us/politics/cpac-stephen-bannon-reince-priebus.html?hp')
print(article.title)
```

Here is the log it shows after I run the code:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py",
>   line 699, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py",
>   line 88, in execfile
>       exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)   File "/home/owner/Desktop/Codes/Newscrawler.py", line 13,
>   in 
>       from ..crawler import commoncrawl_crawler as commoncrawl_crawler SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative
>   import

Comment: What is your directory tree structure? 
Have you added `__init__.py` in each module?

Comment: By tree structure do you mean file adress "/home/owner/Desktop/Codes/Newscrawler.py"? And I didn't add init.py because I installed the module before I write the code.@ParthS007